# What metallic alloys would be used for weapons and armor in the XXI century knighthood games?

Tags: weapons, hard-science, armors, metals

The year is 2035 and Channel 55-KYED decided on a new reality show. the XXI century knighthood games.

It will be your basic renaissance faire re-enactment of medieval combat but since they are doing it in the extraterritorial micronation of Garlandistan they are doing it just like they did in Agincourt: With blood, wounds and the ominous risk of death.

But with a twist, they don't want to use medieval metals. They have a billionaire contract with some big foundries and metallurgic companies that make aerospatial alloys and weapons.

It comes to the picks now. From the modern metal alloys, which ones are the best to make weapons (swords, maces, axes, lances, spears), and which ones are best to make armor (mail, scale, plate) from?

The show is backed by metallurgic companies. There's no budget limit, and ceramics are off. They want to sell metal. For the definition being used, [click here](https://www.chemie-biologie.uni-siegen.de/ac/be/lehre/ceramics_and_alloys.pdf).

Assume no new alloys were invented / discovered between 2020 ~ 2035. This is [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) so it is expected that answers will back their choices with **data** from reputable sources - bonus points for those that compare their alloys with the rejected choices. Social & political aspects are handwaved. Focus on the metallurgy only.

Comment: What is your limit for 'metal' because there are a lot of exciting things going on in the ceramics field, often involving mostly-metal crystals like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxynitride And I can see a neat loophole involving titaium weave and resin.

Comment: Not just ceramics. But various composite materials are lighter and stronger than steel. What's more, you can 3-D print them, then put them through a curing process to harden them. Some with microwaves, some with heat, some other methods. We are just starting to experiment with these materials in our lab.

Comment: @puppetsock, but how are they on impact resistance when compared to steel? Most such materials turn out to be quite brittle.

Comment: @Separatrix Such materials are the preferred material for bullet resistant armor and military helmets these days. Kevlar is one such material. Another in research these days is "spider silk" protein, which turns out to be quite startlingly strong.

Comment: I am always puzzled when hard science question are asked about far future. Which kind of references or studies do you expect?

Comment: @L.Dutch OP specified no advancements in alloys from 2020 onwards, so the date of the setting is just fluff. Presumably they meant _metallurgy_ as a whole, which seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @puppetsock, kevlar is easily cut, the ceramic plates in body armour are specifically sacrificial, they don't take repeated impact. Knife resistant and bullet resistant are very different use cases and we're on knife resistant here.

Comment: Hmm. Now I think about it, traditional armour would have been worn with a gambeson. If you can wear a super-fancy modern gambeson, you could be largely cut-proof...

Comment: @Separatrix if kevlar is so easily cut, how come there are so many specialist tools for doing so? You'll probably find that it is the weave (or lack thereof) of the fibre that makes the difference between bullet-resistant and knife-resistant.

Comment: @Separatrix worries about impact. Also Separatrix, worries about cutting.  Actually, composites can be pretty much designed to have the properties that are required. Strength, resistance to cutting, resistance to impact. Helicopter blades to airport main passenger hall floors to shuttle-type space ship heat shield.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, the specialist tools are because kevlar takes the edge off your scissors really quickly and if you're cutting a lot of it scissors become a significant expense :) In my case it's normally a mixed carbon-kevlar weave and it's hell on cutting edges, also if your cutter isn't really sharp you get scrappy edges and the whole thing is a mess.

Comment: Would it be `medieval combat` re-enactment or `medieval jousting/tournaments` re-enactment? Latter would require more armour and less sharp and durable weapons (jousting lances were designed to break easily, for example)

Comment: @l.dutch I dropped the tag.

Comment: Is this competition going to be voluntary / do the people involve really not care about dying? Because once you start going above a certain grade in terms of materials and cutting power, hits starting turning a lot worse. Taking a direct hit from an iron-wrapped wooden lance is safer than taking a direct hit from a solid titanium lance. I mean, relatively safer.

Comment: 2035 isn't all that far away (15 years).  Why would you expect anything to significantly change from what's used right now?  Most re-enactments are looking for a balance between medieval realism and safety.  In other words, they want the safest metal that most closely resembles the technology of the past.  If that premise is thrown out and cost is no object, I'm voting for armor made up of miniature rail gun solenoids that can deflect the metal tipped lances and the falling bodies of less wealthy (I mean "worthy") knights.

Comment: @JBH This is indeed a question about metallurgy right now, based on the wording in the question and comments.  We can use the extra 15 years to make any necessary changes in culture, since a fight to the death TV show wouldn't fly now.

Comment: Not familiar with [Battle of Agincourt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Agincourt), I looked it up.  "This battle is notable for the use of the English longbow in very large numbers, with the English and Welsh archers making up nearly 80 percent of Henry's army."  Bows and arrows aren't mentioned in your weapons list.  Did you want them to be part of this?  Or are you just doing hand-to-hand combat weapons?

Comment: As a point of realism that you might care about, real full armored knight fighting is nothing like the display put on by Hollywood. It's close, kind of slow, and limited to small sneaky movements, instead of the overt exertions seen on the big screen.

Comment: @Cyn, ren-faire reenactments are a light version of tournaments, bows are really hard to keep non-lethal unless effectively toys. Tournaments are about hitting the other guy until he gives up without permanent damage, so the bow becomes either pointless or a lethal weapon in an environment where lethal force isn't wanted.

Comment: @Separatrix This ain't no Ren Faire.  "...they are doing it just like they did in Agincourt: With blood, wounds and the ominous risk of death."

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to open the bidding with [S1 Steel](http://www.westyorkssteel.com/tool-steel/s1/) covered by [ISO 4957](https://www.iso.org/standard/70646.html)

Rather than being cutting edge science, this is a commercial product. Specifically a shock resistant cold work tool steel. Medium carbon with tungsten and chromium. Ideal for weapons and likely armour as well. Specifically resistant to losing edge and deforming under repeated high impact while maintaining the traditional advantages of steel, low cost, high toughness, easy to work with, good availability.

This is very much a baseline to use as a solution for this question. There may well be exotic alloys with better properties, but then again, there may not.

Comment: S1 steel for what? it is a not a good sword steel, too soft. you want something more like 5160 or 1060. Generally you want something like a high carbon spring steel for swords and armor as well.

Answer (score 2):

### If you don't want steel Aluminium and titanium are your best bets.

For **armor** there are aluminum-steel alloys and titanium alloys. Making armor lighter is the biggest benefit you can gain. For more minor alloying components nickel improves both strength and corrosion resistance of steel.

If you aren't restricted to just improving the metal parts of the armor carbon fiber can make it even better, especially if layered with metals. Better cloth is also a big advantage, making the padding under armor out of modern synthetics means you can have a gambeson that are lighter, stronger, and more flexible that actually breaths, using impact foams you can even get better padding especially in a helmets. Clear plastic eye protection would be excellent.

For **shields** aluminum would be the material of choice as shields are heavy and disposable so the lower performance of aluminum is not a problem, of course carbon fiber would be even better. Titanium would also be an excellent choice it is stronger than aluminum and still reduces the weight.

For **weapons** aluminum is not good, except for reducing weight in things like crossguards and baskets, parts not subjected to repeated stress, it fatigues and fails under repeated loading. Titanium iron alloys are good for many weapons (a titanium hammer would be brutal) but not great for swords it is too soft, however titanium vanadium alloys allows for tempering and can be used to make excellent swords, especially for longer or lighter swords. Even better for a show it makes weapons lighter meaning your "actors" fatigue slower. A titanium-iron core with a steel outside would be an excellent sword composition.

to get away from the metal parts, for polearms (spears, halberds, ect) the possibility of carbon fiber poles would make these weapons far easier to weild, the king of weapons becomes the emperor of weapons.

[Source1](https://www3.nd.edu/~amoukasi/CBE30361/Lecture_Alloys_2014.pdf)

[Source2](http://www.akronsteeltreating.com/docs/default-source/default-document-library/alloying-elements-in-steel-by-t-bell.pdf?sfvrsn=0)

[Source3](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327312753_Microstructure_and_Mechanical_Properties_of_Structural_Metals_and_Alloys)

[Source4](https://www.osti.gov/biblio/6732156)

### Steel

If your fine with steel it depends on the weapon and armor, for swords and armor you generally want a spring steel or something close. 5160 and 1060 are considered the better steels for these, (best is loaded word and depends a lot about the goal and design of the piece. The steel you want for a rapier is different than the steel you want for a katana) although composite steels are also common in swords. For things like hammers you want a slightly softer steel (XX40-XX45), while the best axes use a combination of a hard steel edge and soft steel body.

But the real benefit of modern techniques is better precision at every stage, composition (both chemical and physical) and heat in particular is far better. Just by using modern consistent production and heat treating you are already exceeding medieval metallurgy.

[Study of japanese sword steel microstructure.](http://But%20the%20real%20benefit%20of%20modern%20techniques%20is%20better%20precision%20at%20every%20stage,%20composition%20(both%20chemical%20and%20physical)%20and%20heat%20in%20particular%20is%20far%20better.%20Just%20by%20using%20modern%20consistent%20production%20and%20heat%20treating%20you%20are%20already%20exceeding%20medieval%20metallurgy.)

[Study of damascus steel microstructure](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/104458039090042I)

[Study of european sword microstructure](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/isijinternational/47/7/47_7_1050/_article/-char/ja/)

Comment: What do you mean by "aluminum-steel"? "[Aluminized steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminized_steel)"?

Comment: I have clarified I meant aluminum alloys and Aluminum steel alloy, https://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/news/a13919/new-steel-alloy-titanium/

Comment: Titanium makes for a terrible weapon, as it is rubbish holding an edge (for swords and axes) and its lower density compared to steel makes for unnecessarily large and bulky maces and hammers. It'd make nice armour, though.

Comment: lower density can be an advantage for  mace or hammer, titanium is not aluminum the density is not so low the weapons start to lose effectiveness, it allows for a longer or sturdier impact weapons without the problems of  excessive weight. Titanium by itself does not hold an edge titanium vanadium alloy however holds an edge well.

Comment: @John titanium vanadium is expensive and awkward to produce and machine, and does not exceed the capabilities of a high grade stainless steel. Its kinda academic of course, because using swords against heavily armoured people is stupid (and half-swording is a hack to make inadequate tools doa job they weren't meant to do, in a less convenient way than a decent warhammer or dagger).

Comment: @StarfishPrime the op did say money was not a limitation. Stainless steel is awful sword material,  It has the same problem aluminum does, It suffers  metal fatigue and when if fails it fails completely. I agree swords are a poor choice against fully armored apponents but the OP did ask about swords and use Agincourt as an example only a fraction of soldiers wore full plate in that battle.

Comment: +1 for including scientific sources, given that it's a [tag:hard-science] question.

Answer (score 2):

### Depleted Uranium : for Flails, Two-Handed Hammers/Swords, and Shields

For a swung weapon, mass is the reservoir in which the kinetic energy of a swing or a horse's charge is stored. This reserve of kinetic energy is what tries to foil potential energy reservoir of the target's yield strength times the strain. A high momentum hit will daze the other guy, break bones, numb nerves, and so on.

At 18 thousand $kg \over {m^3}$, [depleted uranium alloys](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5273711A/en) has almost 2.5 times the density of [A36 steel](https://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleId=6117), and a yield strength in the neighborhood of the hardest steels (123ksi, which is equal to 1,100 MPa). Osmium would be 15% better at 22 thousand $kg \over {m^3}$, but I didn't find any reliable sources of industrial Osmium or Osmiridium.

You'd want to wrap your DU (depleted uranium) core in a hard steel. Maybe [chrome alloy Sandvik 13C26](http://www.matweb.com/search/datasheet.aspx?matguid=4eb0b56967464b838e5e947dc95d4272) for edged weapons, but a more durable mild steel like A36 for blunt ones.

For tower shields, you don't want the shield to move. So, DU is the best core material for that purpose. Also wrapped in a durable and mild steel.

### Razor Steel : for Edged Weapons and Armor

[Sandvik 13C26](http://www.matweb.com/search/datasheet.aspx?matguid=4eb0b56967464b838e5e947dc95d4272) boasts a yield strength of (700 to 1,100MPa) and a hardness of 98 Rockwell / 240 Vickers. It's a chrome alloy, and corrosion resistant. I think this would be the best alloy to use for things that need to hold an edge.

### Spring Steel : for Armor

According to MyArmoury.com, the best steel for armor is a good spring steel. The use case for armor is different than weapons, or even shields : the total energy that a weapon must possess to penetrate the armor is the yield strength of the material, multiplied by how much the material will deform before it breaks. Spring steels capitalize on this mix. I'd recommend [Elgiloy](https://www.steel-grades.com/Steel-Grades/High-Alloy/Elgiloy.html) with a 890 MPa yield strength, and 24% max strain.

Comment: Weight for a lance is a bad idea. It needs to be agile as the target may move. The weight is the three quarters of a ton of horse and rider behind the lance.

Comment: Good point. I'll update the answer

Comment: Does uranium hold up? Density doesn't mean strength. A lead hammer would deform and break quickly.

Comment: @fredsbend it does. I've added a hyperlink to the patent application, which includes the material characteristics.

Comment: @458 give it a steel coating? basically what an FMJ bullet is

Answer (score 2):

**This is already happening**

See [Unified Weapons Master](https://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/unified-weapons-master-future-fighting/)

Metal in the armour will be limited to a thin outer layer for appearances only with the inner layers being carbon fiber and impact foam.

Sure it'd be nice to see more metal but really knights won't use that much and the sponsorship logos on the shield will sell more. At the end of the day you have two men hitting each other with weapons therefore you have a obligation to keep them safe as humanly possible which means the best materials for the armour.

The suits for United Weapon Masters is fitted with sensors and lockable joints. If a body part gets hit hard enough the joint locks up and they can't use that part again which means a knight can lose an arm but still win. The suit allows for simulated injuries whilst keeping the wearer safe.

Where metals comes in is the weapons as you need to bypass modern armour if you want actual injuries (which I wouldn't recommend as you want to sell your product but bad publicity could lead to legal action in other countries, human rights violations and sanctions against the sponsor if they can't touch him directly)

At the end of the day selling metal is what matters and the tabard and shield with the sponsor's logo will sell far more metal than the composition of the armour.

Answer (score 0):

Beryllium is as exotic as it gets and it's the lightest usable metal. Due to its rarity only [beryllium copper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beryllium_copper) is made today but certainly better and lighter alloys are possible. Both for armor and for weapons. The downside is, beryllium dust is toxic.

Staying with beryllium copper, the ["extra hard" treated wire has 1415-1620 MPa tensile strength](http://www.lfa-wire.com/heat-treatable-alloy-25_c17200-and-c17300.htm), it can be formed and then hardened, it does not corrode, does not spark...ideal for chain mail!